# Continuity of function that is expressed as the subtraction of two integrals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $\rho\in L^1(R)$ be a given function. We associate it with
$$U(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_x^{+\infty}\rho(y)dy - \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^x\rho(y)dy.$$

Show that $x \mapsto U(x)$ is a continuous function.

My ideas:

Calculate $|U(x)-U(y)|$ and find an expression of type $C| x-y |$ using the mean value theorem for integrals.

Comment: It suffices to show "one of the integrals is continuous". You can use the uniform integrability of $|\rho|$ to do that.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880246/uniform-integrability-of-a-function-in-l1).

Comment: I go to see the post that you give me