# If $u(x):=\int_{x_0}^x v(t)\;dt$, then $u$ locally absolutely continuous.

Tags: lp-spaces, absolute-continuity

I want to show that if $$u(x):= \int_{x_0}^x v(t) \; dt$$, that then $u$ is locally absolutely continuous. The proof in Lemma 3.31 in A First Course in Sobolev Spaces suggests that we first want to show that $v$ is equi-integrable, and then that $u$ is locally absolutely continuous. I am however struggling with both steps.

Suppose $v\in L^p(I)$ is equi-integrable. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\int_F |v(x)|\;d\mu(x) \leq \epsilon,
\end{align*}
for every lebesgue measruable set $F\subset I$ with $\mu(F)\leq \delta$. Let $F$ be any finite disjoint collection of intervals $(a_i, b_i)$ with $a_i,b_i\in I$. Then by the equi-integrability

\begin{align*}
    \epsilon \geq \int_F |v(x)| \geq \int_F v(x)\; d\mu(x)
    = 
    \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{a_i}^{b_i} v(x)\; d\mu(x) 
    = 
    \sum_{i=1}^n u(b_i) - u(a_i).
\end{align*}

**This is close to the definition of absolute continuity, but not quite, since we're missing absolute value bars around the differences in the sum on the right.**

To show that $v$ is equi-integrable (a uniformly integrable collection with only one element) I use [this mathstackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880246/uniform-integrability-of-a-function-in-l1) as suggested by [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18986/david-mitra)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880246/uniform-integrability-of-a-function-in-l1) may help.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you. I didn't know that it was also called uniformly integrable. So now there's only the detail of absolute value bars left.

Comment: Can't you start from the right, with the sum of the absolute values of the differences, then bring the absolute value inside the integral?